Odd and even numbers divisors sum properties with exponential base
Actually during the investigation of some optimization methods, discovered two interesting relations:
$$\sum _{k_{\text{even}}} \frac{\sigma (k)}{e^{\pi  \sqrt{3} k}}=\sum _{k_{\text{odd}}} \frac{\sigma(k)}{e^{\pi  \sqrt{3} k}}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{12 \pi }+\frac{1}{24}$$
$$\sum _{k_{\text{even}}} \frac{\alpha_k\sigma (k)}{e^{\sqrt{3} \pi  k}}=\sum _{k_{\text{odd}}} \frac{\alpha_k \sigma (k)}{e^{\sqrt{3} \pi  k}}$$
where
$$\alpha_k=\left(\pi  k-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right) \left(\pi  k-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right) k$$
The question here is more about the nature of odd and even divisors, I am trying to understand how the factor $$\left(\pi  k-\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right) \left(\pi  k-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right) k$$ can equilize the odd and even divisors sum with the same exponential base.
While without this factor the difference is significant:
$$\sum _{k_{\text{even}}} \frac{\sigma (k)}{e^{\pi  \sqrt{3} k}}=0.00005633806846168702446820799733251584718126191841384486176536369471$$
$$\sum _{k_{\text{odd}}} \frac{\sigma (k)}{e^{\pi  \sqrt{3} k}}=0.00433374602027769115041208285674663596363013528230056592837919871897$$
Below is the plot of subsums of second sum, it is visible how perfectly they match even for small amount of summands:

